# Can I have volume control passthrough to host when focused on guest?

Tags: virtualbox, audio

I have a Linux OS with a Win10 vm using VirtualBox. Everything works fine. But: when I'm focused in the Win10 vm and change volume using keyboard or mouse, it changes the volume in the vm (understandably default behaviour) and not the host. However I'm inevitably listening to music on the host and thus have to click to focus on the host before I can change volume/play-pause/skip etc.

Does anyone know whether I can change this somehow? Thanks!

[image: settings]

Comment: Which virtual machine product is used ?

Comment: Virtualbox. Sorry, I tagged it as this because someone else did the same and it went into the title, but evidently not for me! Edited my post also.

Comment: How are you changing the volume (key & mouse) ?

Comment: keyboard has volume buttons; I have a Roccat Tyon mouse whereby I can use thumbshift+mousewheel for the volume also [https://www.amazon.com/ROCCAT-Tyon-White-Action-Multi-Button/dp/B00LVQTCJ2]

Comment: For the multimedia keys, try to disable automatic keyboard capture in the VM settings.

Comment: bottom right corner, down arrow icon, right click, keyboard settings, extended features: auto capture keyboard: turn off. WORKED. THANK YOU. By all means post as an answer and I'll give you the sweet sweet credit you thoroughly deserve ;)

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the multimedia keys, the solution was to disable automatic
keyboard capture in the VM settings.

Poster remarks : "bottom right corner, down arrow icon, right click,
keyboard settings, extended features: auto capture keyboard: turn off".

With this setting, the problem was solved for the VM.